# how to avoid overlapping of text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a slider on which i am displaying text. but the text needs to be displayed over specific width,

```
<div class="homepage-slider">
    <div id="sequence">
        <ul class="sequence-canvas">
            <li class="bg3">
                <!-- Slide Title -->
                    <div class="title"><? echo $top_text; ?></div>
            </li>
        <ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

css that i used is (had used under media queries)

```
#sequence .title 
    {
        text-align: left;
        margin-bottom: 7%;
        margin-left: -2%;
        font-family: roboto;
        font-size: 28px;
        min-width: 70%;
        overflow: scroll;
        padding:4%;
        position: relative;
    }
```

but the text is getting displayed like this

[image]

can someone please tell how to avoid this overlapping of text

Comment: your code is working fine http://jsfiddle.net/dkhavbvf/

Comment: Looks like a line-height too small. Maybe set somewhere else?

Comment: can you post all the relevant code, so that we can help you.. now we cant come to know you have line-height for div / li.. so post the code or create a demo

Comment: line-height: normal; works bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the `line-height` property to manage the spacing between lines.

```
#sequence .title 
{
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 7%;
    margin-left: -2%;
    font-family: roboto;
    font-size: 28px;
    min-width: 70%;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding:4%;
    position: relative;

}
```

The code which you've shown here doesn't specify the `line-height` property. So I doubt the line-height property is getting inherited to your `.title` from its parent, so just check from where it is getting inherited and set the higher value for it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a line-height issue. Add a "line-height: 1.3" and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Give the text with in the html, so that we can get find the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yup Just add:

```
#sequence .title {
     line-height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.